# Rendering Problems : The Following classes could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, rendering

I am having a problem like many others; I have seen all other similar questions but they have not cleared my problem.

This is my error:

[image: Error]

**The following were suggested to resolve the problem:**

**1)** Changing API from 22(5.1.1) to 21(5.0.1)

*But* I want to work with 5.1.1, so how do I do it without changing to an older version?

**2)** Edit the styles.xml file from:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

*However*, after I do this, In MainActivity.java, my ActionBarActivity seems to be deprecated:

[image: Deprecated]

**3)** Changing the theme to Holo Light/Holo Dark

*But*, I would like to us material theme for my app; How can I resolve the problem without changing the theme? (Furthermore, the deprecated error occurs in this solution too)

***Hence, how do I solve this problem without any side effects as above and why is this happening?***

Answer (score 0):

Google suggest to use Toolbar and then use your toolbar as actionbar. However you have to add this in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

If you add this, actionbar should not be deprecated anymore. Try it please. It worked and working in my project now. Thanks

Comment: Which "gradle file" should I add it to ?

Comment: You should add Module:app gradle file